# Masstransit: Unable to consume messages from the Azure Service Bus

Tags: masstransit

recently I discovered the Masstransit package and decided to give it a try, but I'm a bit stuck.
I'm trying to subscribe to a predefined ASB topic using a predefined subscription.

I have a topic with the following name:
[image]

Also, I created the following subscription:
[image]

Here is my masstransit configuration:

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(provider =>
{
    provider.AddConsumer<UpdateEmployeeConsumer>();

    provider.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, config) =>
    {
        config.Host(serviceBusConnectionString);

        config.UseConsumeFilter<MessageLoggingFilter>(context);

        config.SubscriptionEndpoint(
            "search-service",
            "employee-changed",
            endpoint =>
            {
                endpoint.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 1;

                endpoint.UseConsumeFilter<CustomerDataPropagationFilter<UpdateEmployeeMessage>>(context);
                endpoint.ConfigureConsumer<UpdateEmployeeConsumer>(context);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

When I run the service, message are not consumed and I see "Bus stopped: {service bus url}" message.
Here are logs:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing, without enough log data to really know, that the credentials to connect to Azure Service Bus are invalid (or the permissions are insufficient).

If you configure a `StartTimeout` and maybe event `WaitUntilStarted`, the process will wait until the connection is established or prevent the service from starting. The configuration [is in the documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration#host-options).

Comment: Hey Chris, you're right, looks like the problem is misconfigured permissions. Once I set WaitUntilStarted flag I started receiving permissions error. Will be looking into that, thank you!